# PHP email glitch

Tags: php, email, mysqli

This is a school assignment. I don't know all of the fine details of PHP variables and such, but! If I hardcode the id then it sends just like it should. If not, it doesn't at all. Suggestions?

```
if ((!empty($_subject)) && (!empty($_text))) {
        $_dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'db') or die ('Error Connecting to MySQL server.');

        $_id = $_GET['id'];

        $_query = "SELECT * FROM midterm WHERE id = '$_id'";

        $_result = mysqli_query($_dbc, $_query) or die ('Error Querying Database.');

        while($_row = mysqli_fetch_array($_result)) {
            $_to = $_row['email'];
            $_firstName = $_row['firstName'];
            $_msg = "Dear $_firstName, /n $_text";
            mail($_to, $_subject, $_msg, 'From:' . $_from);         
            echo 'Mail sent to: ' . $_firstName . ' at ' . $_to . '<br />';
        }
```

Comment: how's that related to mail(), that should be your query problem..

Comment: [MySQLi prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Read it, use them. Also, you have no logic to deal with zero results found. I think this is where your code is failing

Comment: Thanks! I have a similar file that works just fine with that mail() but the only difference is that it doesn't have the WHERE part in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Please update this question with the output of `var_dump($_GET['id'])`.  Also I second the two above comments, but that doesn't help your problem.

Comment: what is var_dump($_GET['id'])? SHould I just use it instead of $_GET['id']? Really new here with PHP.

Comment: var_dump() will return all the information about the variable (in this case $_GET['id']).  I am just requesting this for debugging information. http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I get NULL @Sam Sullivan.

Answer (score 0):

**Addressing $_GET/$_POST problems with a NULL $_GET['id']**

`<form name="example" action="http://example.com" method="POST"></form>`

OR

`<form name="example" action="http://example.com" method="GET"></form>`

If variables are POSTed from a form, they will be sent through the server and you can access them on the submitted page with $_POST['key'].  If variables are sent with GET, they will be appended to the URL in a query string and accessible on the page with $_GET['key'].

When you use the variable `$_GET['id']` it is looking in the URL's query string for the key `id`.  If your URL looked like `http://example.com/sript.php?id=123` then `$_GET['id']` would return `123` not `NULL`.  This can either be accomplished by visiting a specific URL (like shown above) or arriving on the page through a form like below:

```
<form name="example" action="http://example.com/script.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="id" />
<input type="submit" value="Try Me" />
</form>
```

This form, when submitted, will send the $_GET['id'] variable to script.php using GET.

**Addressing other issues with mail not sending**

Can you add the following lines of code before your while loop and let me know what they say?  This will let me know if your MySQL query is working.

```
echo "Rows returned: ".mysqli_num_rows($_result)."<br />";

// this line only works on PHP > 5.3.0
echo "Result dump:<br /><pre>".mysqli_fetch_all($_result)."</pre>";
```

Since mysqli_num_rows() returned 0, that means that your SQL query `SELECT * FROM midterm WHERE id = '7'` is not returning any results.  I can't help any more without looking at the database structure.  Double check your code (and compare it to code that works) to try to see what is going wrong.  Make sure that there is a row in the table midterm that has an id = 7.

Comment: Alright then. I do to that page from a "contact" link. I do kind of understand how POST and GET work but so far I haven't had to REALLY explore all of their wonderful properties.

Comment: If this is for a contact link, then you would want to link to the URL `http://example.com/contact.php?id=123` vs `http://example.com/contact.php`.

Comment: I have this on my page with contact links: Correct? Wrong?

echo '<a href="MT_vjones_contact.php?id=' . $_row['id'] . '&amp;date=' . $_row['date'] .
      '&amp;firstName=' . $_row['firstName'] . '&amp;lastName=' . $_row['lastName'] .
      '&amp;email=' . $_row['email'] . '&amp;phone=' . $_row['phone'] .
      '&amp;expertise=' . $_row['expertise'] . '&amp;skills=' . $_row['skills'] .
      '&amp;avatar=' . $_row['avatar'] . '">Contact ' . $_row['firstName'] . ' ' . $_row['lastName'] . '</a></td></tr>';

Comment: And when I am on the page that send the email the link above is: 
`http://dgm3760.inkedkeyboard.com/MT_vjones_contact.php?id=7&email=floridaflash2000@yahoo.com`.

Comment: I would only include the id (since this is a unique identifier) in the URL, and retrieve everything else from the database once you click the link.  So `echo '<a href="MT_vjones_contact.php?id'.$_row['id'].'">Contact</a>';`

Comment: On the page you linked in your last comment, `$_GET['id']` will be equal to 7.  If you use your script in the question, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: Can you confirm that `var_dump($_GET['id']);` does not return `NULL` anymore (this is a great debugging resource)?

Comment: It now says `string(1) "7"`.

Comment: Here's what the page says on after submit on the send page: Rows returned: 0

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in /home/inkedkey/public_html/dgm3760/MT_vjones_contact.php on line 91.

Comment: Rows return 0 means the SQL query didn't find any results, so either the ID does not exist or your query is wrong (not invalid because no errors are generated).  The call to undefined function is because your PHP version does not include mysqli_fetch_all().

Comment: Well, thank you very much anyway. All the IDs are there. So I'll just keep trying. Thanks!

Comment: My final suggestion is to experiment with a GUI MySQL client (graphic) like phpMyAdmin.  This will let you create and test SQL statements quickly and efficiently as well as easily create SQL code through a UI.  Learning is better this way.  I'd appreciate an upvote if I helped at all.